# Desk Top Gone After Changing Driver

Tags: drivers, screen

Ok, I am an Ubuntu complete newbie, and while I was trying to get to know my new system better, it seems that I changed the screen or the video driver to something wrong, and the desktop was gone, only one big picture, no sidebar no icons... nothing. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu (12.04) but no use. I run Firefox by launching the terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and write the name of the program just as it is "Firefox" and it worked with me!
Any advice? Unfortunately I chose to install it to work beside the Win7 and now I have multi-boot, if this is information is going to be useful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem after I installed the latest Nvidia driver. You have to go back and use the default driver.

1. Go to **System Settings → Software Sources → Additional Drivers** and select **Nouveau** display.
2. Then restart by pressing the power button on the computer till it restarts.

It will then boot up looking normal again.